# wpf comboBox selectedIndex=0 is not working

Tags: wpf, combobox

**.xaml**

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="cbx_srchResOrg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding InfoCombo}" SelectedIndex="0" DisplayMemberPath="Dis_name" SelectedValuePath="Hide_id" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectInfo}"/>
```

Here is a part of my source code.
Why ***'SelectedIndex=0'*** is not working?
I want to select [0] value to default at first time, but it just empty box at run time. There are no errors except it. How can I fix it?

Comment: A cleaner way IMO https://stackoverflow.com/a/47022374/5154345

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Hej said, you have binded the `SelectedItem` with a property in your view model which was `null`.

You can fix this by assigning the `SelectedItem` in your Viewmodel constructor

```
Public MyViewModel()
{
    SelectInfo = InfoCombo[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are already binding to SelectedItem. It binds two way by default, so if the property binded to it(SelectInfo) is null, it will also be set to null.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Mode=OneWayToSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `SelectedItem` binding with `SelectedIndex="0"`.

In your case:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" 
          Grid.Column="1" 
          x:Name="cbx_srchResOrg" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding InfoCombo}" 
          SelectedIndex="0" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Dis_name" 
          SelectedValuePath="Hide_id" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectInfo, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

Like others said, it binds two way by default, so if the property binded to it (SelectInfo) is null, it will also be set to null.

Answer (score 1):

you have bind `SelectedItem` to `SelectInfo`, you should set value(in your viewmodel) to `SelectInfo` as default, for example

`SelectInfo = InfoCombo[0]` or something other whatevere you want to set as default value