# WPF ComboBox Items in UserControl size not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, user-controls

I have a user control. This user control is created from code and through binding it already receives changes although it's not yet visible. It is at some point "set visible" by assigning it to a ContentHolder's Content (It is the second page in a setup dialog):

```
ContentHolder.Content = GamePreparation;
```

In my user control I have a ComboBox that I currently fill manually:

```
BoxGuestColor.Items.Clear();
if( Game?.CurrentTeamGuest != null )
{
    foreach( var color in ( (TeamElement)Game.CurrentTeamGuest ).Colors )
    {
        var item = new Rectangle
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush( FromHex( color ) ),
            Height = 16,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
            Tag = color
        };
        BoxGuestColor.Items.Add( item );
    }
    if( BoxGuestColor.Items.Count > 0 )
    {
        BoxGuestColor.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

As you might see from the code, I'm using the ComboBox to display a few colors. I'm putting rectangles into the ComboBox since I only want to display a color and nothing else.

Now this all works well! My problem is that when the control is shown, I don't see the selected element. Only when I click on the arrow to open the ComboBox an update is triggered and I get to see all elements (including the selected one).

Using the debugger I figured out that the selected item is valid but its width and height are both 0. The items are set to Stretch as VerticalAlignment, but it seems that the update "doesn't reach" the items. They are not rescaled when the user control is shown. This happens when I interact with the ComboBox as described above.

I also tried to embed the rectangle into a ComboBoxItem with the same effect:

```
var item = new ComboBoxItem
{
    Height = 16,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
    Tag = color,
    Content = new Rectangle
    {
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush( FromHex( color ) ),
        Height = 16,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
        Tag = color
    }
};
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? Thank you in advance!

*Edit 1:*

The XAML is straight forward:

```
<ComboBox Name="BoxGuestColor" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="BoxGuestColor_SelectionChanged"/>
```

*Edit 2:*

Please note that the ComboBox has a variable width depending on the parent window's size. Using hard-coded widths (for instance on the Rectangle) fixes the update problem, but it leaves me with those rectangles never filling out the ComboBox, which simply doesn't look good.

Comment: add the view also in here

Comment: Do you set other properties of `ComboBox`, like `SelectedItem`? That could be a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43061376/1997232).

Comment: added the XAML code which is straigth forward. I do not touch any other properties except what I've shown here.

Comment: Are you sure that you are loading data into correct combo-box? Since your XAML shows "BoxHomeColor" and in your code, it shows "BoxGuestColor". My guess is that you have two combo-boxes and you are verifying the other or loading the wrong ones. Just let us know.

Comment: Apologies! I copied the wrong piece from the XAML. Yes, there are two ComboBoxes, both being handled basically the same. I did not fill the wrong one, only pasted the wrong name here.

Comment: Not being able to find a solution for my problem, I have decided to go with the workaround of using fixed widths. This is terrible UI design, but I don't see any other way right now and I don't have time to look any further. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you fill it in before the control is shown, try updating the binding of the .SelectedIndex property once the control is displayed.

This will inform the view that it needs to display the first item in the list.

Comment: Yes, I fill the ComboBox before it is shown. I also set the SelectedIndex before the control is shown. I'd still expect an update of the sizes to be performed when the control is shown.
I don't know what event to use for "when it's shown". The user control doesn't have one. I tried using the SizeChanged event of the user control and the combo box, but both were executed before the Items were modified (which seems right, but doesn't let me change the SelectedIndex late enough)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I got an error when I used your code because of control name "BoxGuestColor" which does not exists in current context. So I changed it to "BoxHomeColor". Hope you are not updating a diff. combobox and checking the other.

Second thing when I tried with your code, initially it did not showed me the selected one once the window is loaded. After adding explicitly Width="100" (Some random value) in code-behind, it started showing the selected one. See below code,

```
      BoxHomeColor.Items.Clear(); if( Game?.CurrentTeamGuest != null ) {
      foreach( var color in ( (TeamElement)Game.CurrentTeamGuest ).Colors )
      {
          var item = new Rectangle
          {
              Fill = new SolidColorBrush( FromHex( color ) ),
              Height = 16,
              Width = 100,
              VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
              Tag = color
          };
          BoxHomeColor.Items.Add( item );
      }
      if( BoxHomeColor.Items.Count > 0 )
      {
          BoxHomeColor.SelectedIndex = 0;
      } }
```

But in your case if you can't hard-code the width in code-behind, then try to set width to the combo-box explicitly and assign the Width of Rectangle from BoxHomeColor.Width like below,

```
            <ComboBox Name="BoxHomeColor" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"
            SelectionChanged="BoxHomeColor_SelectionChanged" Width="400"/>

            BoxHomeColor.Items.Clear(); if( Game?.CurrentTeamGuest != null ) {
            foreach( var color in ( (TeamElement)Game.CurrentTeamGuest ).Colors )
            {
                var item = new Rectangle
                {
                    Fill = new SolidColorBrush( FromHex( color ) ),
                    Height = 16,
                    Width = BoxHomeColor.Width,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                    Tag = color
                };
                BoxHomeColor.Items.Add( item );
            }
            if( BoxHomeColor.Items.Count > 0 )
            {
                BoxHomeColor.SelectedIndex = 0;
            } }
```

Hope this way you can give a try, but if you can't hard-code the width even in xaml for combo-box, then we might think to solve it some other way. But let us know your views after trials.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I copied the wrong piece of XAML, apologies! Using hard-coded widths works. I have tried this before. However in my case the ComboBox has a variable width depending on the window's size. And I want the ComboBoxItems  to fill out the whole ComboBox's width. So, using a fixed width for those rectangles would be my fallback - but it's not a pretty one.

Comment: @le_fritz at any point of time, if you are not providing the width for the combo-box item, it will be zero and you can't see it, how ever you can try with this Width="{Binding ElementName=YourWindowName, Path=Width/ActualWidth}" but it will increase the combo-box item to the width of the Window (it might looks big the moment when you expand the items, but you can use this statement with a converter and can adjust the width of a combo-box item. Hope this helps if there is no other way which you cannot hard-code the width at the combox-box item or in the code-behind.

Comment: Thanks. I can set widths at several different positions - fixing the update issue at the cost of a good visual appearance. However the idea is that I don't have to set the width. I'm using a flexible layout - something I like about WPF. In my opinion at the point the control is shown, it should be resized (it is). This should trigger resizing in all children elements including the ComboBox Items. So either there is a bug or I somehow break this resizing hierarchy.